# How to dismiss input fields without first responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, first-responder

I am on a viewController having textField being first responder, then a view gets instantiated on some call back method, but the keyboard still gets open on the instantiated viewController, I have tried to dismiss the keyboard by `[self.view endEditing:YES]` but it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the [self.view endEditing:YES] in viewDidDisappear

Answer (score 0):

Use default overide function of viewcontroller

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi go to mainStoryBoard and just check the checkMark on auto enable returnkey if it is same as you mainStoryBoard so then return back to your code

```
/// the method where  view is getting instantialte before view get Instantite use this here is sample.

  [self resignKeyBoard];
```

[image]

```
// goto your code here is uiButton with close icon 

 - (IBAction)closeKeyboardPressed:(id)sender {

 cellTypeButton*btn=(cellTypeButton*)sender;

if(btn.selected){
    btn.selected=false;
    [self resignKeyBoard];
}else{
    btn.selected=true;
    [self resignKeyBoard];
}

}


-(void)resignKeyBoard{

closeKeyBoardBtn.hidden=true;

[PhoneNumTxt resignFirstResponder];
[codeTxt1 resignFirstResponder];
[usernameField resignFirstResponder];
[fullnameField resignFirstResponder];
[statusField resignFirstResponder];
[Utilities animateDownTextField:PhoneNumTxt inView:self.view];
[Utilities animateDownTextField:codeTxt1 inView:self.view];
[Utilities animateDownTextField:usernameField inView:self.view];
[Utilities animateDownTextField:fullnameField inView:self.view];
[Utilities animateDownTextField:statusField inView:self.view];

[self.view endEditing:YES];
}



 //// have a good day :D
```